# What might cause the 'InternalServerError executing request' when running a manually triggered pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

The setup of the pipeline is a simple import from a `.csv` file stored in Azure Blob Storage to an Azure SQL database table.
When I run the pipeline in Debug by using the 'Debug' button in the portal, the job finishes in 8 seconds.
When I run the pipeline with the `Add trigger\Trigger now` button it runs for 20+ minutes and fails with the error 'InternalServerError executing request'.

I recreated the pipeline and components from scratch and tried using a Data Flow (Preview) and a Copy Data, both give the same result.

The expected output is a successful run of the pipeline, the actual output is the 'InternalServerError executing request' error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with source control, which we recently enabled. The 'Add trigger\Trigger now' uses the published version of the pipeline. The Debug uses the currently saved version of the pipeline. The 20 minutes timeout and the 'InternalServerError executing request' is a poor way of saying: 'You did not publish your pipeline yet' :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another possible cause in case someone else stumbles upon this:

I had the same error multiple times when I had many concurrent pipeline runs, in my case triggered by hundreds of new files in a OneDrive folder ("manually" triggering the pipeline via Azure Logic App). Some of the runs succeeded, some of them failed. When I reran the failed runs or loaded fewer files at once, it worked.

So the Data Factory might not be ready yet to handle parallel execution very well.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another possible cause in case someone else stumbles upon this:
Check if the data factory is down from the Resource Health tab.
I was getting Internal Server Error for all the sandbox runs.